# Mysql Query Execution time takes second to result?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table which has following structure

--

### -- Table structure for table `visitors`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visitors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visited_by` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ip` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser_short_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser_version` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `os_platform` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visited_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_visited` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

### -- Table structure for table `numbers`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `numbers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Table visitors has total record as 172,153 and Table numbers has total record as 5,896

I am trying to fetch record for last 30 days using following query

```
select  
x.ts AS timestamp,
COUNT( y.`id`) as no_of_visitors,
DATE( y.`visited_time`) as visited_date,
MONTH( y.`visited_time`) as month_visit,
MONTHNAME( y.`visited_time`) as visit_month_name,
WEEKOFYEAR( y.`visited_time`) as visit_week_no,
YEAR( y.`visited_time`) as year_of_visit
from 
  (SELECT  date(DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY)) AS ts
                 FROM numbers n
                WHERE DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY) <= CURDATE( )) x 
LEFT JOIN  
visitors y 
ON  
date(y.`visited_time`) = x.ts 
GROUP BY DATE(x.ts) 
order by DATE( x.ts) desc
```

It took  4.7833 sec to execute in localhost. what i had done wrong in query ?
How do i execute the query as much fast? Kindly advice

Comment: Perhaps even something as simple as indexing your table on `visited_time`? If you're going to work with databases, you really should learn about indexes - they're what make databases fast.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks. I have used this ALTER TABLE `visitors` ADD INDEX (`visited_time`); but seems same sec to result

Comment: Why does the query use `CAST(n.id as SIGNED)` ?

Comment: @kordirko Hello, I think `numbers.id` is `UNSIGNED` and OP is trying `UNSIGNED - 30` this gives error `ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't you just want:

```
select
COUNT( y.`id`) as no_of_visitors,
DATE( y.`visited_time`) as visited_date,
MONTH( y.`visited_time`) as month_visit,
MONTHNAME( y.`visited_time`) as visit_month_name,
WEEKOFYEAR( y.`visited_time`) as visit_week_no,
YEAR( y.`visited_time`) as year_of_visit
from 
visitors y 
where y.`visited_time` > date_add(curdate(), interval -30 day)
group by DATE(y.`visited_time`) 
order by DATE(y.`visited_time`) desc
```

The entire thing with the numbers table causes a very large join operation that is inefficient and unnecessary I think, though I don't understand really what you're doing with the table numbers...

**EDIT:**
If you want all dates, I would join after the above query finishes:

```
select * from
all_dates a left join 
(select
COUNT( y.`id`) as no_of_visitors,
DATE( y.`visited_time`) as visited_date,
MONTH( y.`visited_time`) as month_visit,
MONTHNAME( y.`visited_time`) as visit_month_name,
WEEKOFYEAR( y.`visited_time`) as visit_week_no,
YEAR( y.`visited_time`) as year_of_visit
from 
visitors y 
where y.`visited_time` > date_add(curdate(), interval -30 day)
group by DATE(y.`visited_time`) 
order by DATE(y.`visited_time`) desc) b
on a.date = b.visited_date;
```

where obviously all_dates is your dates table you made.

Comment: Hello, I totally agree with you if `GROUP BY DATE(y.visited_time)` has all days from min date to max date. But according to `LEFT JOIN` I think some dates are missing. Also, I think your query is good for speed, and It is better that missing date is filled by client side. (sorry my bad English if you could not understand my comment)

Comment: @InoSHeo i use number table for missing dates.

Comment: Okay, but how do you define "all dates"? Which dates do you need to have? Just the last 30 days?

Comment: @reverse_engineer let me try your advice

Comment: @reverse_engineer seems works fast as expected. Let me check once again

Answer (score 1):

There are two consideration

- `DATE(y.visited_time)` = x.ts

  - This can't use INDEX even if visited_time is INDEXed.
- GROUP BY DATE(x.ts) ORDER BY (x.ts)

  - also can't use index even if GROUP BY DATE(y.visited_date)

If you really speed up your query, I suggest that add additional field to store DATE part of visited_time and make it INDEXed. e.g

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visitors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visited_by` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ip` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser_short_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser_version` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `os_platform` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visited_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `visited_time_dt` DATE,
  `is_visited` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  INDEX(visited_time_dt),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

then your final query looks like as follows and faster (I guess)

```
SELECT  
    x.ts AS timestamp,
    COUNT( y.`id`) as no_of_visitors,
    DATE( y.`visited_time`) as visited_date,
    MONTH( y.`visited_time`) as month_visit,
    MONTHNAME( y.`visited_time`) as visit_month_name,
    WEEKOFYEAR( y.`visited_time`) as visit_week_no,
    YEAR( y.`visited_time`) as year_of_visit
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
        date(DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY)) AS ts
    FROM 
        numbers n
    WHERE
        DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY) <= CURDATE( )
) x LEFF JOIN visitors y ON y.`visited_time_dt` = x.ts 
GROUP BY y.visited_time_dt
ORDER BY y.visited_time_dt desc
```

### UPDATE

What about this? `z` table returns only 1 record with MIN, MAX value. this MIN/MAX values are joined with `visitors.visited_date_dt`

```
SELECT  
    x.ts AS timestamp,
    COUNT( y.`id`) as no_of_visitors,
    DATE( y.`visited_time`) as visited_date,
    MONTH( y.`visited_time`) as month_visit,
    MONTHNAME( y.`visited_time`) as visit_month_name,
    WEEKOFYEAR( y.`visited_time`) as visit_week_no,
    YEAR( y.`visited_time`) as year_of_visit
FROM  numbers n 
WHERE
  (
    SELECT
        date(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY)) AS ts
    FROM 
        numbers n
    WHERE
        CURDATE() >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY
   ) x
   LEFF JOIN visitors y ON y.`visited_time_dt` = x.ts 
   INNER JOIN
   (
        SELECT
            MAX(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY)) AS max_ts,
            MAX(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY)) AS min_ts,
        FROM 
            numbers n
        WHERE
            CURDATE() >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY
   ) z ON y.visited_time_dt BETWEEN z.min_ts AND z.max_ts
GROUP BY y.visited_time_dt
ORDER BY y.visited_time_dt desc
```

Comment: @Dinesh Ooops. sorry. Just reduced by 3.28%. :(. Are all `DATE(col_name)` replaced to `visited_date_dt`? Could you post output of `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'x LEFT JOIN visitors2 y ON y.`visited_time_dt` = x.ts INNER JOIN ( ' at line 18

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on `visited_time`

```
CREATE INDEX `visited_time_ix` on visitors( `visited_time` );
```

and try also this query:

```
select  
x.ts AS timestamp,
COUNT( y.`id`) as no_of_visitors,
DATE( y.`visited_time`) as visited_date,
MONTH( y.`visited_time`) as month_visit,
MONTHNAME( y.`visited_time`) as visit_month_name,
WEEKOFYEAR( y.`visited_time`) as visit_week_no,
YEAR( y.`visited_time`) as year_of_visit
from 
  (SELECT  date(DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY)) AS ts
                 FROM numbers n
                WHERE DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY) <= CURDATE( )) x 
LEFT JOIN  
visitors y 
ON  
date(y.`visited_time`) = x.ts 
WHERE y.`visited_time` >= (  SELECT min( date(DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY)) )
                                                 FROM numbers n
                                                 WHERE DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY) <= CURDATE( ) 
        )
      AND y.`visited_time` <=  (  SELECT max( date(DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 29 DAY)) )
                                                 FROM numbers n
                                                 WHERE DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL CAST(n.id as SIGNED) - 30 DAY) <= CURDATE( ) 
        ) 
GROUP BY DATE(x.ts) 
order by DATE( x.ts) desc
;
```